# SQL Server and SQLite replication of data via USB (Android)

Tags: android, sql, web-services, sqlite, usb

I have a project which I am trying to sync SQL server database and SQLite database via usb. I can currently connection directly to the SQL Server database via WiFi and use this data real time or I can sync the two databases so that the data is replicated. Can this be done via USB? I have read about developers using a web service to connect via USB. If so how can I connect to the web service via USB? I have look at possible every “Stackoverflow” page that had to do with “Android, USB, SQL, SQLite and Web services".

So my Questions are:

- Is there a way to connect to SQL Server via USB to replicate the data from an (Android device) SQLite database?
- If so what API’s can I use to do this?
- If web service is require for communication via USB to a SQL server database, how can I connect to the web service via USB?
- I have looked at the Restful technology and I like the light weight of the communication. Can this be used to communicate via USB?

Thank to all that will help!